# Ansible | Why is the Mellanox 'onyx_interface' module failing?

Tags: ansible

My Mellanox task role:

```yaml
---
- name: set mellanox
  set_fact:
    ansible_network_os: 'onyx'
    ansible_connection: network_cli

- name: configure interface Eth1/2
  mellanox.onyx.onyx_interface:
    name: Eth1/2
    mtu: 1500
```

My playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: mellanox_switch
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - mellanox
```

The error (verbose 3) it produces:

```json
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_mellanox.onyx.onyx_interface_payload_8h8n_8qc/ansible_mellanox.onyx.onyx_interface_payload.zip/ansible_collections/mellanox/onyx/plugins/module_utils/network/onyx/onyx.py", line 158, in get_capabilities
    capabilities = connection.get_capabilities()
  File "/tmp/ansible_mellanox.onyx.onyx_interface_payload_8h8n_8qc/ansible_mellanox.onyx.onyx_interface_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py", line 200, in __rpc__
    raise ConnectionError(to_text(msg, errors='surrogate_then_replace'), code=code)
fatal: [192.168.1.4]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aggregate": null,
            "delay": 10,
            "description": null,
            "enabled": null,
            "mtu": 1500,
            "name": "Eth1/2",
            "purge": false,
            "rx_rate": null,
            "speed": null,
            "state": "present",
            "tx_rate": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "show version | json-print\r\r\n% Unrecognized command \"json-print\".\r\nType \"?\" for help.\r\n\r [standalone: master] > "
}
```

What is odd, is that the `onyx_command` module works just fine:

```yaml
---
# Mellanox management
- name: set mellanox
  set_fact:
    ansible_network_os: 'onyx'
    ansible_connection: network_cli

- name: test show version
  onyx_command:
    commands: show version
```

Not sure what the issue is. Thinking it might be installation related.

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add the following lines to the playbook

```yaml
  become: yes
  become_method: enable
```

Comment: Right, according the ["latest" documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/networking/display/Onyxv391014/Ansible), for a connection attempt `become: yes
become_method: enable` should be included within the playbook.

Answer (score 1):

> *Why is the Mellanox `onyx_interface` module is failing?*

According the error message

```
show version | json-print
Unrecognized command "json-print"
```

the reason seems to be somehow related to the module source code [`module_utils/network/onyx/onyx.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/mellanox.onyx/blob/master/plugins/module_utils/network/onyx/onyx.py#L114).

The [Community Collection Mellanox Onyx](https://galaxy.ansible.com/mellanox/onyx) module [`onyx_interface` module – Manage Interfaces on Mellanox ONYX network devices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/mellanox/onyx/onyx_interface_module.html) will import from his own module utilities (see [`modules/onyx_interface`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/mellanox.onyx/blob/master/plugins/modules/onyx_interface.py#L125))

```py
from ansible_collections.mellanox.onyx.plugins.module_utils.network.onyx.onyx import BaseOnyxModule
from ansible_collections.mellanox.onyx.plugins.module_utils.network.onyx.onyx import get_interfaces_config
```

and try to find the version and capabilities of the Remote Device.

It tries to format the result output to JSON according

```py
def show_cmd(module, cmd, json_fmt=True, fail_on_error=True):
    if json_fmt:
        cmd += " | json-print"
    conn = get_connection(module)
```

That specific command `| json-print` is either not available on the Remote Device, there are no capabilities for, or rights are missing. This explains also why the command `show version` only was working.

To narrow down the cause you should also try to execute

```yaml
---

# Mellanox management

- name: Address Mellanox environment 
  set_fact:
    ansible_network_os: 'onyx'
    ansible_connection: network_cli

- name: Test 'show version'
  onyx_command:
    commands: show version | json-print
  register: result

- name: Show result
  debug:
    var: result
```